# Writing drakma http-request array to file

Tags: arrays, stream, common-lisp

What I want to do:
take the output of `(drakma:http-request "someURL.jpg")` and write it to a file. The output consists of a byte array.

What I came up with:

```
(with-open-file (my-stream "thing.jpg" 
                           :direction :output
                           :element-type 'binary 
                           :if-does-not-exist :create
                           :if-exists :supersede)
  (let ((content (drakma:http-request "someURL.jpg")))
    (loop for i across content do
      (write-byte i my-stream))))
```

The error I get:

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread #<THREAD "initial thread" RUNNING
                                                {1002978FB1}>:
  could not find any output routine for :FULL buffered BINARY
```

I use SBCL 1.0.49.
If you want any other info or find my question unclear then please, ask away :).

EDIT:
The problem is the :element-type, it's supposed to be 'unsigned-byte.
You can find information on the different possibilities of :element-type over at the Common Lisp Hyper Spec under [open](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_open.htm) . Other than that everything is correct.

PS. I couldn't respond as an answer because my reputation is too low.

Comment: Better would be `(unsigned-byte 8)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Xach said, you're better off using `'(unsigned-byte 8)` (or make a type-definition , e.g. `(deftype binary () '(unsigned-byte 8))`).

In addition, you can probably replace your loop over the array and writing byte by byte with a call to `write-sequence`